# CSS Nested lists items and alternate background

Tags: html, css, nested-lists

I am searching for a way to have list items have alternating background colors. When there is a nested list the items keep alternating but the child is indented without having the background color of the parent flow down to its nested children. [image: nested list example]

It is not possible to apply classes. Also the amount of items is variable. Preferably it should work for an infinite amount of nested lists. But if that is not possible a cap on 3 depths (as in picture) should be enough. If it is easier to do by using divs instead of li and ul, that is also possible for me. I prefer pure HTML/CSS.

Because all my experiments did no good I can only supply a JSFiddle with the nested lists.

https://jsfiddle.net/qmdwpzt8/1/

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1-1</li>
        <li>Item 1-2
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1-2-1</li>
                <li>Item 1-2-2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 1-3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 2
    <ul>
        <li>Item 2-1
            <ul>
                <li>Item 2-1-1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>    
</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS only. Requiring an element to have knowledge of its parent's element is impossible in CSS. CSS only cascades down to child elements. While a top level or nested `li` can know its siblings, the decedents cannot know if it's parent was odd or even. Therefore, it cannot repeat the pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one potential solution: https://jsfiddle.net/qmdwpzt8/3/

Not sure if all your requirements will be met by it, but I updated your list with `div`'s:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>Item 1</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>Item 1-1</div></li>
            <li><div>Item 1-2</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><div>Item 1-2-1</div></li>
                    <li><div>Item 1-2-2</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><div>Item 1-3</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div>Item 2</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>Item 2-1</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><div>Item 2-1-1</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li><div>Item 3</div></li>
    <li><div>Item 4</div></li>
</ul>
```

And then add background colors with jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var b = true;
    $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
        b = !b;
        if (b) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#00ff00");
        }            
    });
});
```

This does depend on jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: As doing it with pure CSS does not seem to be possible, this answer is probably the easiest to use